# In iis, what does having multiple authentication types on the same app enabled imply?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I've gone too long just telling myself, well this just works so I'll treat it as a black box.

I can enable anonymous, forms, windows security, etc... But if I enable multiple of them on the same path/app, what does that mean? Do they all run? Does the most secure take the role of verification?

Is there a point to enabling anonymous and windows authentication?

Is there a way to step through the authentication process?

Answer (score 1):

This article is for older versions for Windows Server, but the logic is the  same
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/264921

When the browser makes a request, it always considers the first request to be Anonymous. Therefore, it does not send any credentials. If the server does not accept Anonymous or if the Anonymous user account set on the server does not have permissions to the file being requested, the IIS server responds with an "Access Denied" error message and sends a list of the authentication types that are supported by using one of the following scenarios:

- If Windows Integrated is the only supported method (or if Anonymous fails), then the browser must support this method to communicate with the server. If this fails, the server does not try any of the other methods.
- If Basic is the only supported method (or if Anonymous fails), then a dialog box appears in the to get the credentials, and then passes these to the server. It attempts to send the credentials up to three times. If these all fail, the browser does not connect to the server.
- If both Basic and Windows Integrated are supported, the browser determines which method is used. If the browser supports Kerberos or Windows NT Challenge/Response, it uses this method. It does not fall back to Basic. If Windows NT Challenge/Response and Kerberos are not supported, the browser uses Basic, Digest. The order of precedence here is Basic, Digest.